# PHP multi-select filter with Ajax post request with DataTables

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to convert an existing "select" dropdown filter on a table generated via the DataTables library to be able to handle multiple options, and though I think I have it correct on the front-end Javascript, I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle it in the back-end PHP.

The below is from the script in the front-end view, which makes the Ajax Post request:

```
<script>
    function generateTable() {
        var oTable = $('#MyData').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [
                [1, "desc"]
            ],
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
                [10, 25, 50, 100, 200]
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": <?= $Settings->rows_per_page ?>,
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '/my/getData/path',
            'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                // ...SNIP...

                aoData.push({
                    "name": "some_status",
                    "value": $("#some_status").val()
                });

                $.ajax({
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': sSource,
                    'data': aoData,
                    'success': fnCallback
                });

            },

            "aoColumns": [],

        }).fnSetFilteringDelay().dtFilter([
            // ...SNIP...
            {
                column_number: 4,
                filter_default_label: "[<?= lang('some_status'); ?>]",
                filter_type: "multi_select",
                data: []
            },
            // ...SNIP...

        ], "footer");

    }
</script>
```

I can confirm that the selected values are added to an array by console logging the `$("#some_status").val()`. So my assumption was that it would be passed to the backend as an array as well, but apparently not.

What actually happens is the first selection goes fine, but any subsequent selection clears the table, and only works if there's a single value selected, leaving me to believe that only the first selection is pushed to the `aoData` array.

In PHP I have:

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables
    ->select("id, date, reference_no, supplier, some_status")
    ->from('purchases');

$some_status = $this->input->post('some_status');
if ($some_status != '') {
    $this->datatables->where('status', $some_status);
}
```

How do I handle the `some_status` value if it's an array, or how do I make sure it even is an array after it was pushed to`aoData`?

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:
To clarify, by console logging the result like below returns the correct selection as I add and remove selections from the multi-select dropdown:

```
console.log($("#some_status").val());
```

If I select "Top option" from the dropdown, I get:

```
[
    "top_option"
]
```

When I then select "Another option" as well, I get:

```
[
    "top_option", "another_option"
]
```

So the JS side is handling the multi-select, but I don't know if the below is correct, as it works only with a single select, nothing more:

```
$some_status = $this->input->post('some_status');
if ($some_status != '') {
    $this->datatables->where('status', $some_status);
}
```

Comment: what's the value of js $("#some_status").val()?

Comment: With one item selected I get ['the_item']. With multiple I get ['the_item', 'the_other_item']

Comment: you need to clarify your question with the exact name of the POST variables you use and how you get them in PHP

Comment: anyway if you want to have an array in PHP, you must use square brackets in the name of the variables in HTML. ex. "myvariables[]"

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear

I meant to say that when I log the `$("#some_status").val()` to console I get the selected valued as intended. For whatever 'select' option there is, if I click it, I get it as an array in the console. 

How will your "myvariables[]" example above be incorporated with the PHP I posted in my orignal question?

Comment: you are still not clarifying your question. Try with this: "name": "some_status[]",

Comment: Hi @GiacomoM, I added some clarification in my original post, sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you want clarity on.

Comment: you did not try what I wrote: "name": "some_status[]",

Comment: I did, sorry for not saying so, but the table doesn't render when I do.